# OpenCV 2.4.5 android, FeatureDetector, DescriptorExtractor

Tags: android, opencv, javacv, orb

Using OpenCV-2.4.5-android-sdk, 
I try to match two images with feature detection (ORB detector and hamming matcher). Unfortunateley, I'm always getting a NullPointerException when computing the descriptors. What am I doing wrong?

```
        FeatureDetector detector = FeatureDetector.create("ORB");
        DescriptorExtractor descriptor = DescriptorExtractor.create("ORB");
        BFMatcher matcher = new BFMatcher(Hamming.normType, true);

        KeyPoint keypoints1 = new KeyPoint();
        KeyPoint keypoints2 = new KeyPoint();
        CvMat[] descriptors = new CvMat[2];

        //ORB orb = new ORB();

        //orb.detect(image1, null, keypoints1);
        detector.detect(image1, keypoints1, null);
        descriptor.compute(image1, keypoints1, descriptors[0]);

        detector.detect(image2, keypoints2, null);
        //orb.detect(image2, null, keypoints2);
        descriptor.compute(image2, keypoints2, descriptors[1]);

        // matcher should include 2 different image's descriptors
        DMatch matches = new DMatch();
        matcher.match(descriptors[0], descriptors[1], matches, null);
```

I wonder, if I have a change to perform feature detection with openCV on Android without android-ndk.  Would you suggest trying to write and integrate native c++ code?

**Update:** After restructureing the project's setup, following this: http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html#dev-with-ocv-on-android description, the code looks like this:

```
    FeatureDetector detector = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.ORB);
    DescriptorExtractor descriptor = DescriptorExtractor.create(DescriptorExtractor.ORB);
    DescriptorMatcher matcher = DescriptorMatcher.create(DescriptorMatcher.BRUTEFORCE_HAMMING);

    MatOfKeyPoint keypoints1 = new MatOfKeyPoint();
    MatOfKeyPoint keypoints2 = new MatOfKeyPoint();
    Mat[] descriptors = new Mat[2];

    //ORB orb = new ORB();
    //orb.detect(image1, null, keypoints1);
    detector.detect(image1, keypoints1, null);
    descriptor.compute(image1, keypoints1, descriptors[0]);

    detector.detect(image2, keypoints2, null);
    //orb.detect(image2, null, keypoints2);
    descriptor.compute(image2, keypoints2, descriptors[1]);

    // matcher should include 2 different image's descriptors
    MatOfDMatch matches = new MatOfDMatch();
    matcher.match(descriptors[0], descriptors[1], matches);
```

The NPE still occurs.

Comment: I assume that you get the exception at the first occurrence of `descriptor.compute`. Try to have two instances `descriptors1` and `descriptors2` instead of a CvMat[]. If it doesn't help, try to print the number of keypoints after `detector.detect`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You are right, the error occurs at the first call of `desriptor.compute`. I tried to have two instances `descriptors1` and `descriptors2` but then I got the LogCat output: `OpenCV Error: Bad argument (Unknown array type) in cv::Mat cv::cvarrToMat(const CvArr*, bool, bool, int), file /home/saudet/projects/javacv-cppjars/opencv-2.4.5/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 698` In my test example, the keypoints1's size after `detector.detect` was 31. I am not sure, if this is the number of keypoints.

Comment: Have you tried to use `Mat` to store images and descriptors, instead of `CvMat`? `CvMat` is now obsolete; consider using `Mat` instead. It might fix the issue with the exception.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, too. I cannot find Mat in `opencv_core` or else where in `com.googlecode.javacv.cpp`. And the method `compute` in `DescriptorExtractor` has the signature `void com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_features2d.DescriptorExtractor.compute(@InputMat CvArr arg0, @StdVector KeyPoint arg1, @OutputMat CvMat arg2)`.

Comment: oh, you are using JavaCV, my bad.

Comment: Try another algorithm than ORB (for instance FAST + BRIEF), and tell us if you still have the same error.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have missed allocating objects to the `descriptors[]` array.

```
    descriptors[0] = new CvMat();
    descriptors[1] = new CvMat();
```

Answer (score 0):

Allocate objects eg.

```
Mat descriptortwo = new Mat();
```

and then remove the null argument from the optional mask parameter, like so:

```
detector.detect(image1,keypoints1);
```

Think it should do the trick :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to initializate thouse matrix.
 Instead of saying `Mat[] descriptors = new Mat[2];`

try:
 `Mat descriptors1= new Mat();
    Mat descriptors2= new Mat();`